How do I choose individual colors for contours in matplotlib
In my short python code below I am plotting risk levels based on values in a csv file and using a shapefile. The code works, but I would like to select specific individual colors for each level, namely green, yellow, orange and red.
Currently it works if I put "Blues", or "Reds" as in the attached png.[.
The line in the code
merged_df.plot(column="risk",colors = ['green','yellow','cyan','red'])

does not work.
How do I specify individual specific colors. help will be appreciated.
The risk data in "Tmaxrisks.csv" is as
"District","risk"
"Berea",1
"Butha Buthe",3
"Leribe",1
"Mafeteng",2
"Maseru",1
"Mohale's Hoek",2
"Mokhotlong",4
"Qacha's Nek",3
"Quthing",3
"Thaba Tseka",4


import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map_df = gpd.read_file("Shapefiles/BNDA_LSO_1990-01-01_lastupdate/BNDA_LSO_1990-01-01_lastupdate.shx")

risks_df = pd.read_csv("Tmaxrisks.csv")

merged_df = map_df.merge(risks_df, left_on=["adm1nm"], right_on=["District"])

merged_df.plot(column="risk", cmap="Reds", legend=False)
#merged_df.plot(column="risk",colors = ['green','yellow','cyan','red'])

plt.show()


Thanks, this is exactly what i want but instead of cyan I want orange. I put cyan because I thought orange was not recognised.

Oops, you replied to your own post. Anyways, just change cyan to orange in d. It's not a big deal.

You can map the district to each adm1nm, then the risks to the colors, and pass it to plot :
d = {1: "green", 2: "yellow", 3: "cyan", 4: "red"}

colors = map_df["adm1nm"].map(risks_df.set_index("District")["risk"].map(d))

ax = map_df.plot(color=colors, edgecolor="k", alpha=0.7)

Plot (showing the risks) :

NB: I'm using this dataset to define map_df.

Thanks infinitely @Timeless, you really saved my day. Just one more help, in the title I want to include the date. I tried plt.title("High Temperatures Risks $day/$month/$year)", y=1.04), having already imported date an defined today = date.today(), day=today.day, month=today.month, year=today.year. Thanks

You're welcome ;). You can use strftime like this : from datetime import date; plt.title(f"High Temperatures Risks {date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}", y=1.04)

Follow up question posted
